# Scale panels one below other in one container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have these widgets in my html, using Bootstrap panels:
[image]

Why is my second line LEFT widget scales accordingly first line RIGHT widget height, and not immediately below that first left widget height? They are in the same container.

Is there some solution to this, but solution which will hold them in same container?

Comment: Maybe is better use flebox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please add enough code to your question to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use jQuery and set a class `.same-height`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    var heights = $(".same-height").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".same-height").height(maxHeight);
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/4g1v415r/)**

Comment: Purpose is not to have all columns same height, but to append widget below other widget without gaps if they are not same height.

Comment: @firstChild - So you want the 2nd box in the left column to be higher up?

Comment: That's right, to follow below widget of the same column, not right column.